# Installing R package from github returns non-zero exit status error; GSL and Rtools correctly installed

Tags: r, devtools, gsl, rtools

I'm attempting to install the mvabund package from github here on Windows 10 in R 3.5.1 (The github version has functions not yet available in the cran versions.): https://github.com/aliceyiwang/mvabund

I've installed Rtools, using the instructions for another package here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynr/vignettes/InstallationForUsers.pdf

and all the checks there indicate that GSL and RTools are installed properly.

However, when I try to install the package with devtools, it throws the following error:

```
> devtools::install_github("aliceyiwang/mvabund")
Downloading GitHub repo aliceyiwang/mvabund@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp69joKy\remotes22b417af510c\aliceyiwang-mvabund-530676b/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'mvabund': (1.9s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (2.3s)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'mvabund_4.0.tar.gz'
   Warning: file 'mvabund/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Joshua/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'mvabund' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -IC:\Program Files\R\local323\/include -I. -I../inst/include -I"C:/Users/Joshua/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Joshua/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RcppGSL/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++.exe: error: FilesRlocal323/include: No such file or directory
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mvabund'
* removing 'C:/Users/Joshua/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/mvabund'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Joshua/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp69joKy/file22b479083376/mvabund_4.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Session info posted below:

```
    > devtools::session_info()
- Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 os       Windows >= 8 x64            
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_Australia.1252      
 ctype    English_Australia.1252      
 tz       Australia/Sydney            
 date     2018-12-12                  

- Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.0   2017-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 backports     1.1.2   2017-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 callr         3.1.0   2018-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 cli           1.0.1   2018-09-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 devtools      2.0.1   2018-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 fs            1.2.6   2018-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 glue          1.3.0   2018-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgbuild      1.0.2   2018-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 processx      3.2.1   2018-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 ps            1.2.1   2018-11-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 R6            2.3.0   2018-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 Rcpp        * 1.0.0   2018-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 remotes       2.0.2   2018-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rlang         0.3.0.1 2018-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rstudioapi    0.8     2018-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 testthat      2.0.1   2018-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 usethis       1.4.0   2018-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)

[1] C:/Users/Joshua/Documents/R/win-library/3.5
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library
```

Any help in getting this package to install would be appreciated.

Comment: can you tell us what operating system (windows, ubuntu, mac) are you using, also, which version of r you have, if you could paste in your question the output of `devtools::session_info()` it would help. Thanks

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735407/r-not-recognizing-gsl-library-undefined-references/53741012#53741012

Comment: Do you have Rtools installed?