# R not recognizing GSL library undefined references

Tags: r, devtools, gsl, rtools

I am installing a package from github in R (link here: https://github.com/aliceyiwang/mvabund), using devtools. I have installed Rtools, using the instructions for another package (here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynr/vignettes/InstallationForUsers.pdf) and all the checks there indicate that GSL and RTools are installed properly.

I've set the Windows system environment variables LIB_GSL (as `"C:/R/local323"`) and PATHS (as `"C:/RTools/bin/", "C:/RTools/mingw_64/bin", "C:/R/R-3.5.1/bin"`)

I also run the following code in R before installing the package:

```
Sys.setenv("LIB_GSL" = "C:/R/local323")
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/")
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:/RTools/bin/",
                        "C:/RTools/mingw_64/bin", "C:/R/R-3.5.1/bin", sep = ";"))
```

**Question:**

When I run:

```
devtools::install_github("aliceyiwang/mvabund")
```

The code initiates well and starts installing the package. There comes a point, however, when this happens:

```
[...excluded very long list of undefined references like that below...]
summary.o:summary.cpp:(.text+0x194c): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_free'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    no DLL was created
    ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mvabund'
    * removing 'C:/R/R-3.5.1/library/mvabund'
    In R CMD INSTALL
    Error in i.p(...) : 
      (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/Joshua/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsPp5oY/file2154340c11f8/mvabund_4.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

My guess is that somewhere, some path to those functions has not been defined properly. What am I doing wrong?

My session info is

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] usethis_1.4.0  devtools_2.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.8    magrittr_1.5      pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.3.0          rlang_0.3.0.1    
 [7] tools_3.5.1       pkgbuild_1.0.2    sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.0.1         withr_2.1.2       remotes_2.0.2    
[13] yaml_2.2.0        assertthat_0.2.0  digest_0.6.18     rprojroot_1.3-2   crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.2.1   
[19] callr_3.1.0       fs_1.2.6          ps_1.2.1          curl_3.2          testthat_2.0.1    memoise_1.1.0    
[25] glue_1.3.0        compiler_3.5.1    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.2   prettyunits_1.0.2
>
```

Comment: Just a guess but you generally have to set environment variables outside of R (ie "system level") and then restart R to take effect.  Also note that i) `mvabund` is on CRAN ii) you can just install it from CRAN iii) It is just about the oldest package using Rcpp so we have almost 10 years of making this work iv) it works reliably at win-builder and on CRAN.  So whatever is wrong is at your side -- maybe time to revisit what the R manual 'Writing R Extensions' and 'Installation and Administration' as well as winbuilder etc have to say about GSL and variables.  It all works fine on Linux....

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I realise I can install mvabund off CRAN, but it doesn't have the latest version. I've set the environmental variables outside R, and restarted R. I then set the environmental variables inside R as well. Linux is no good to me, unfortunately.

Comment: I would backtrack and remove moving parts -- standard debugging tricks. Once `install.packages("mvabund")` works I am sure the desired GH installation will too.  Until then you are currently fighting more layers of obfuscation than I would be comfortable with.

Comment: I installed mvabund it with `install.packages("mvabund") ` then ran the github install again. However, the same error persists....

Comment: Thinko on my part. I forgot that you're on Windows where you get a prebuild binary from CRAN. So that proved nothing. Back to you for debugging.  Try a source install from CRAN (or from a local .tar.gz).

Comment: Ok, so I ran `install.packages("mvabund", type = "source")` and got the same error. Just to test things out - I installed packages 'easypackages' and 'vegan' from source as well, and they worked.

Comment: If I were you I would focus on your GSL issue and try other GSL-using packages.  And I am going to remove the `Rcpp` tag above -- your problem is entirely local as your setup is not as required for installation from source.  There is no bug in any of the listed packages.

Comment: Ok. Since mvabund does not install from the CRAN source, the problem is my setup. Do you have any information or links for how to install and use the GSL library in R? I've spent hours trying to get this to work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to include the entire answer to this problem, since it exists nowhere else in one spot, which fixes the errors in this question, and in this one: [Installing R package from github returns non-zero exit status error; GSL and Rtools correctly installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718871/installing-r-package-from-github-returns-non-zero-exit-status-error-gsl-and-rto)

Before doing anything, make sure that R is not installed into a location with spaces in the file name. For example, we don't want C:\Program Files\R, because that has a space, and, as we all know, spaces let in the death bots, which destroy your installation.

Then install RTools (and, when you install RTools: no spaces in the file name... may take a while to install) and the GSL libraries following VERY CLOSELY the Windows instructions here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynr/vignettes/InstallationForUsers.pdf

(GSL libraries for R here:
http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/libs.html
Rtools here - download the latest Frozen version (for now: Rtools34.exe): 
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Then we download a zipped copy of the package from https://github.com/aliceyiwang/mvabund 
and unzip it in our working directory.

Now, using the above installation method, the GSL libraries are in two folders, one for each of the i386 and x64 architectures. Unfortunately, the Makevars.win file in the mvabund github version is not set up to distinguish between the architectures in that setup, as it has only one path for PKG_LIBS.

So, clear the Makevars.win file and replace it with:

```
## This assumes that the LIB_GSL variable points to working GSL libraries
CXX_STD = CXX11
ARCH=x64
ifeq "$(WIN)" "64"
ARCH= i386
else
ARCH= x64
endif
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I$(LIB_GSL)/include -I. -I../inst/include
PKG_LIBS=-L"$(LIB_GSL)\lib"$(R_ARCH_BIN) -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

Then we run the following code. Replace the file paths with your file paths.

```
Sys.setenv("LIB_GSL" = "C:/R/local323") # Replace file path here; this is the GSL library location, same as you specified for LIB_GSL in the windows environment 
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/") # Replace file path here
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:/RTools/bin/", sep = ";")) # Replace file path here
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/$(R_ARCH_BIN) -lgsl -lgslcblas")
Sys.setenv("PKG_CPPFLAGS"="-I$(LIB_GSL)/include -I. -I../inst/include")

# this assumes you have unzipped the mvabund download in your working directory
file.rename("mvabund-master", "mvabund")
shell("R CMD build mvabund")
install.packages("mvabund_4.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL) #may need to replace file name
library("mvabund")
```

Let's run an analysis, then:

```
abund <- mvabund(dataset[,8:39]) #community matrix section of spreadsheet
treatment <- as.character(dataset$Treatment) #treatment variable
## pairwise comparison 
manyglm(abund ~ treatment) -> msolglm
anova(msolglm, pairwise.comp = treatment, nBoot = 9) #pairwise comparisons make it run longer
```

Comment: But the [src/Makevars.win used by the CRAN version](https://github.com/cran/mvabund/blob/master/src/Makevars.win) is simpler too.  Maybe the architecture gets embedded in the environment variable separately for each architecture -- I simply don't know.  But I trust what works for CRAN and win-builder, and that is [this file](https://github.com/cran/mvabund/blob/master/src/Makevars.win).  (Then again Alice just saw a need to update it slightly....)

Comment: I know. I checked that out before doing the above. All I want to do, however, is run the package, whether or not it's the way CRAN does things, and the above answer works.

Comment: Sure. Not to be pedantic but for that should also be able to a) use the existing `src/Makevars.win` with b) compile/build of just one arch, say 64 bit and c) corresponding library locations.  But anyway -- you have it working.  I am just not a fan of answers implying to know better than "upstream" -- I'd trust the authors.

Comment: I agree. I tried every way I could think of to fix my installation without touching the package. In the end though, I didn't really have a choice. There was no other solution I could find.

Comment: this is straight up too clunky, I would rather reimplement the libraries in fucking assembly